# Concern was Second to none

Tags: meaning-in-context

What is the meaning of this sentence . "On his own part, Sir William Jones's concern was second to none. "? I have interpreted that he was equally concerned like others.

Comment: Goodness me that is so easy to find synonyms: *incomparable, matchless, unrivalled, ...* It means that Sir William Jones's was as concerned as he could be, although I have never seen this phrase applied in this way.

Comment: @WeatherVane 'on his own part' would mean?

Comment: I think your example is probably "Indian English". In "standard" English, the idiom is ***For** his own part*. But it doesn't really suit the context anyway, since it's usually followed by a clause describing something the subject (***him = Sir William***, here) actually *did or said* as his contribution to some collective endeavour. Simply being as concerned as anyone else isn't really a suitable "contributing activity" in such contexts.

Comment: Source please. Please give a detailed citation of the source, and if possible a link. Full context is very important in such questions.

Answer (score 3):

The phrase "on his own part" means "regardless of what anyone else was doing", and is more usually written "**for** his own part".

The phrase "second to none" means "none better", such as in a race: not in second place.

So the whole sentence

> On his own part, Sir William Jones's concern was second to none.

Does not mean what you suggest — "he was equally concerned like others" but

> Regardless of anyone else's actions, Sir William Jones could not
>   have been more concerned.

Comment: Arguably, Sir William Jones could have been *much* more concerned than he actually was (whatever the problem was, I bet he didn't sell up all his assets and devote the rest of his life to resolving it as an unpaid volunteer). All we know is that no-one else was *more* concerned than him.

Comment: @FumbleFingers his concern could have been *emotional*.

Comment: I'm tempted to point out that in such contexts, "being concerned" is *always* an emotional response! :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers perhaps Sir William *was* that concerned — we don't know the full story.

Comment: True. But it's an example of a "not-quite-superlative" usage where in practice we tend to assume more than has been explicitly claimed. If you said to your sweetheart *Nobody could love you more than me*, you'd be a bit crestfallen if she took that as implying there might be plenty of rival suitors who could love her *as much* as you.

Comment: @FumbleFingers as you commented below the question, "second to none" isn't really an appropriate phrase to use in this context anyway. When I was in India I read the English language newspapers with some amusement, as stories could be a collection of idioms strung together, but actually saying little of value.

Comment: I never said (or certainly didn't *intend* to say) that ***second to none*** was "inappropriate" in the cited context. I was objecting to the use of ***On his own part***, which even after "correction" to ***for his own part*** doesn't really work very well for me. To my mind, idiomatic *for his/my [own] part* normally precedes a statement saying *what he/I **did*** (as his/my contribution to some process or problem). And "being concerned" (even if it's *more* concerned than anyone else) isn't really a "contribution". But you're right - *My concern is better than yours*, say, is "weird".

Comment: @FumbleFingers I paraphrased your: *Simply being as concerned as anyone else isn't really a suitable "contributing activity" in such contexts.*